# When selecting drop down, getting jquery error

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have some code like this

```
<div class="section-hdr">Add Item</div>
<div style="width:75%;margin-left: 150px;">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditOrderModel", "Orders", null))            
    {
    @Html.EditFieldFor(x => x.Id)
    <a href="javascript: AddOrderItem();" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:15px;" id="saveOrderItem"><i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i>&nbsp;Save</a>            
    }
</div>
```

Problem is the form gets created but when I select the dropdown (EditFieldFor) the javascript crashes. I have played with a lot of options to get the dropdown working but I don't understand why it doesn't work.

The function AddOrderItem() is never actually hit.

Here is the error message in firebug

> f is undefined
>
> range:c.validator.format("Please enter a value between {0} and
>   {1}."),max:c.validator.format("Please enter a value less than or equal
>   to {0}."),min:c.validator.format("Please enter a value greater than or
>   equal to
>   {0}.")},autoCreateRanges:false,prototype:{init:function(){function
>   a(e){var
>   f=c.data(this[0].form,"validator");e="on"+e.type.replace(/^validate/,"");f.settings[e]&&f.settings[e].call(f,this[0])}this.labelContainer=c(this.settings.errorLabelContainer);this.errorContext=this.labelContainer.length&&

Comment: We would need to see the code of the `AddOrderItem()` fn to have a chance at answering this.

Comment: AddOrderItem is never called. I am calling this form in two different places. In one place (where it works) I select the drop downs and then the function is called. But here (where it does not work) I select the drop down and and jquery throws an exception and my function is never called.

Comment: Looks like an error to do with validation. We'd need to see more code.

Comment: Just to make sure I rewrote AddOrderItem() to make sure.      function AddOrderNoteItem() {
                    debugger;
                    alert("test");
                }

Comment: Turns out it works in Chrome but not Firefox. It breaking the firebug debugger every time.